# Return business results via API?

Tags: google-search-api

We are trying to update our database of customers using Google.  We have a list of our customers business name, address, city, state and zip.  We are then opening a google search instance and 90% of the time the top business listed is our customer.

Is there a way to have that data available as an API or automated feed through an API or some other search feature?

This could obviously be abused by spammers which is why our data is so accurate.  We need to verify our customers information prior to sending out mail drops and while writing an project that could visit our customer's website, crawl the page for address, parse out the data using Google would be much easier and hopefully more up to date.

Anyway have suggestions or samples out there?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for public data like addresses etc, your best bet will be Google Places API. It lists a lot of local businesses. E.g. by using it's text search functionality you can issue a similar request to the one you are sending now on google.com:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests

There are samples listed on the page and a js library to get you started.